# Why does ./configure give me unmet packages, that do not exist?

Tags: compiling, dependencies

I'm trying to compile [Caribou 0.4.18.1](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/caribou/0.4/) on `Xubuntu 14.04`.

In the `INSTALL` document it says, that I should run `./configure && make && make install`.

But the `./configure` step ended with:

```
checking for python platform... linux2
checking for python script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
checking for python extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
checking for CARIBOU... no
configure: error: Package requirements (
  pygobject-3.0 >= 2.90.3,
  gtk+-3.0      >= 3.0.0,
  clutter-1.0   >= 1.5.11,
  gdk-3.0       >= 3.0.0,
  x11,
  atspi-2
  ) were not met:

No package 'pygobject-3.0' found
No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
No package 'clutter-1.0' found
No package 'gdk-3.0' found
No package 'atspi-2' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables CARIBOU_CFLAGS
and CARIBOU_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Trying to install any of these packages fails, because they're not in the package index.

I've seen this with some other programs I wanted to compile, so it seems to be a problem with my machine.

Could someone explain to me, what the error is actually saying and what I can do against it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependencies are expressed not as package names, but as `pkg-config` dependencies. I think that on RPM-based systems you can search for these directly, but on Debian-based systems you need to search for the corresponding files.

To do that, the easiest approach is to install `apt-file`, update its indices with

```
sudo apt-file update
```

then you can use `apt-file search` with the dependencies. In your case:

```
apt-file search pygobject-3.0.pc
apt-file search gtk+-3.0.pc
```

and so on. (`.pc` files contain the information necessary for `pkg-config`.) This will tell you that the packages you need to install are respectively `python-gi-dev` for `pygobject-3.0`, and `libgtk-3-dev` for `gtk+-3.0`; I'll let you figure out the rest.

You can perform the same search online using https://packages.debian.org (the results will generally work on Xubuntu as well).

With a little more work you can use `apt-cache search` too;

```
apt-cache search gtk+-3.0 | grep -- -dev
```

should produce the appropriate package name (amongst others possibly).

As pointed out by [K1773L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/18269/k1773r), since `caribou` is packaged in Xubuntu, you can run

```
apt-get build-dep caribou
```

to get the build-dependencies, but that will give the dependencies of the version that was packaged; in general if yours is different then you may need different dependencies.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the quick answer. Is there another approach, besides using `apt-file`?

Comment: just use apt-get build-dep / apt-cache search

Comment: As [K1773R](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/18269/k1773r) says, you can use `apt-cache search` and look for `-dev` packages, or in this particular case `apt-get build-dep caribou` (but that will match the version that was packaged, which may not be the same as the version you're building). You can also use the package search interface on https://packages.debian.org which will give package names appropriate for Xubuntu as well.

Answer (score 1):

As caribou is in the repositories, you can just run
`sudo apt-get build-dep caribou`
to install all dependencies.